# Building Full Page Web Apps

Tags: html, css, web-applications

Im trying to build a full screen web application I really like what MobileMe has done where the whole screen is taken up so it resembles a native desktop application.

I'm looking for tutorials on the topic of designing web apps. I cant seem to find anything on the interwebs.

These are the sorts of things im trying to design:
www.mobileme.com
http://280slides.com/Editor/
https://gomockingbird.com/mockingbird/

BUT - Its not a very complex app, so I don't really want to use any sort of js framework. All I want to create is the html / css and minimal javascript. Unless there is a framework thats small and nimble, I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend looking at the tutorial [100% Height Layout using CSS](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/?p=144) which goes into detail in at least how the full height will work. From there you can decide how to layout horizontally.

Comment: Thanks, I found this earlier today, I must have skimmed over it.